Get Specific Files (Only Specific Extension Type All Files in Loop ) from Media
I want to get Specific Extension Files from Media of Current Post Uploads—for Instance, .jpg or .png or .pdf, or MP4. (Get Only 1 Extension All Files From Current Post Uploads)
Specific Extension Files
I am Success in All Attachments or Images but I Need Help in Specific Extensions Files.
The code is Here:


if ( have_posts() ) : 
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'attachment', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'post_status' => null, 
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID 
        );
        
    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {

//Get All Attachment of Current Data ()
$getallattachments = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, $size = '', $icon );
$parsedAllAtachmentURL = parse_url($getallattachments);
$pathAllAtachmentURLinfo = pathinfo($parsedAllAtachmentURL['path']);
$AllAtachmentURLfilename = $pathAllAtachmentURLinfo['filename'];
$AllAtachmentURLextension = $pathAllAtachmentURLinfo['extension'];
$AllAtachmentalt_text = get_post_meta($attachment->ID, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);
$AllAtachmentcaption = wp_get_attachment_caption( $attachment->ID );
$AllAtachmentimage_title = $attachment->post_title;  

$AllAtachmentgetSizeKBsonly = filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment->ID ) );
$AllAtachmentgetSizeKBMB = size_format( filesize( get_attached_file( $attachment->ID ) ), 2 );

//Get Data of All Attachment Extension Files
echo "All Attachments URL: ". $getallattachments. "";
echo " All Attachments File Name without Extension: " . $AllAtachmentURLfilename . "";

echo  " All Attachments Extension Only: " .$AllAtachmentURLextension. "";
    
    if(!empty($AllAtachmentalt_text)){
    echo "  All Attachments Alt Text: " .$AllAtachmentalt_text.  "";
    }
    else {
         echo  "  Alt Field Doesn't Exist for Attachment or Empty Field in Image: " .$AllAtachmentURLfilename . "";
    }  
    
    
echo " All Attachments Title Text: " . $AllAtachmentimage_title.  ""; 
echo " All Attachments Caption: " . $AllAtachmentcaption. "";
echo " All Attachments Kbs Only: " .$AllAtachmentgetSizeKBsonly. "";
echo " All Attachments KBs MBs Sizes: " .$AllAtachmentgetSizeKBMB. "";




//for Specific Extensions (Need Help Here Get Specific Extension Files)
$getspecificextensionfileurl = strpos( wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID ) , '.doc or .pdf etc') )          
            


 
//Echo Here
 




        }
    }
endwhile; 
endif; 




You don't need to use strpos() to figure out the extension because you've already parsed the URL above and stored the extension in $AllAtachmentURLextension, so all you need to do is
//for Specific Extensions
if( 'docx' == $AllAttachmentURLextension ) {
  // docx handling here
}
elseif ( 'pdf' == $AllAttachmentURLextension ) {
  // pdf handling here
}


In $AllAtachmentURLextension All Media FIles will get, I just need help to get "Specific Extension files" from media, for example, .pdf or.docx. Please follow //for Specific Extensions (Need Help Here Get Specific Extension Files) section from code.

I've updated my answer for clarity. Remember, you're setting $AllAttachmentURLextension within the foreach loop, so it's actually referring to each individual file's extension.

On the Following code Not Getting the URL whereas the file available in uploads both pdf and docx: I just need only URL in Text.
`




Get PDF".$getallattachments; ?>
`